# Finding the maximum order of an element of $U(4) \times U(9) \times U(5)$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-sum, direct-product

I would like to find the maximum order of an element of $U(4) \times U(9) \times U(5)$. I know that $U(4) = U(2^2)$, and $U(9) = U(3^2)$. So I get that $U(4) \times U(9) \times U(5) = U(2^2) \times U(3^2) \times U(5).$

I also know that $U(2^2) \cong \mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z$ and $U(3^9) \cong \mathbb Z_6$. So we get that $U(2^2) \times U(3^2) \times U(5) \cong (\mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z) \oplus \mathbb Z_6 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$.

Clearly, the maximum order of an element of $U(4) \times U(9) \times U(5)$ is finite. But one of the isomorphism theorems I've applied above tells me that that particular maximum order of an element of $U(4) \times U(9) \times U(5)$ is equal to the maximum order of an element of $(\mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z) \oplus \mathbb Z_6 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$, which is, in fact, infinite. I don't get this at all.

$(\mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z) \oplus \mathbb Z_6 \oplus \mathbb Z_4$ would have infinitely many elements since $\mathbb Z_2 \oplus\mathbb Z$ has infinitely many elements.

Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $U(2^2)\cong \Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: So we have $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_4×\Bbb Z_6$.  We should have an element of order $12$.

Comment: How come it says in my notes though that for all $k$ greater than or equal to $2$, $U(2^k) \cong \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}$. In our case, we chose $k$ to be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$U(4)\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

We wind up with $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_6×\Bbb Z_4\cong\Bbb Z_2×(\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_3)×\Bbb Z_4\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2×(\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_4)\cong\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_{12}$.

There is thus an element of order twelve.

Comment: But in my notes, it says that for all $k$ greater than or equal to $2$, $U(2^k) \cong \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}$. In our case, we chose $k$ to be equal to $2$.

Comment: If $k=2$, you get $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_1\cong\Bbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of notation.

Remember that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ actually means the quotient group $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$, i.e., the group of integer remainders modulo $n$.

So $\mathbb{Z}_1 \cong \mathbb{Z} / 1\mathbb{Z} \cong \{0\}$, the trivial group. The only possible remainder when dividing by 1 is 0. So $\mathbb{Z}_1 \ncong \mathbb{Z}$! A reasonable mistake to make!